# Check a check box if another check box in same row is chekd in a GridView

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, checkbox

I have a Gridview, each row with two check box, on the check of second checkbox i want the first check box to be checked automatically.I'm looking for Clent side scripts...Please help

Comment: If you are using jQuery you can write function which will iterate through your table and bind change event of each second checkbox.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
var rows = $("#your table tr:gt(0)"); // skip the header row

rows.each(function(index) {
    var lastCheckbox = $("td:nth-child(youlast checkbox cell) input", this);
    var firstCheckBox=$("td:nth-child(firstCheckboxCellIndex) input", this);
    $(lastCheckbox).change(function(e) { $(firstCheckBox).attr('checked',$(this).is(':checked'));
});;
```

Comment: hi i chnaged the code like this    $(document).ready(function () {
            var rows = $("#GrdMenuConfig tr:gt(0)"); 
            rows.each(function (index) {
                var lastCheckbox = $("td:nth-child(4) input", this);
                var firstCheckBox = $("td:nth-child(3) input", this);
                $(lastCheckbox).change(function (e) {
                    $(firstCheckBox).attr('checked', $(this).is(':checked'));
                });
            });
        });  
but it doesn'tworks...!!